# A function whose derivative is $(\tan x-1)(\tan x-2)$. Then find point of local maximima and local minima.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

A function whose derivative is $(\tan x-1)(\tan x-2)$. Then find point of local maxima and local minima.

**Approach:** $f'(x)=(\tan x-1)(\tan x-2)$ at $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$   derivative is $0$ and derivative is changing sign in neighbourhood of $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. So $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ must be point of maxima.

But when I plot $f(x)=x+3\log(\cos x)+\tan x$ in desmos, I am not seeing any maxima or minima. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the plot you've used. The local extrema are clearly visible in [WolframAlpha's plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x+%2B+3+log%28cosx%29+%2B+tanx+from+0+to+pi%2F2)

Comment: **Desmos** is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type $\log x $  into Desmos  it uses $ \log_{10}  x.$  If you switch to $\ln x $  it gives $ \log_{e}  x,$  which is what you require.

To experiment for yourself, just type in $ \log x$   and see what value it shows at $x=10.$

[image]

[image]